# How can I initialize a table object in a database if a condition is met? cakephp

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I want to create a waitlist table for a class table. so if the max number of students have already enrolled in the class then any new registering student will be put into waitlist table. the admin can specify if a class has a waitlist or not.  if the admin approves of the student then they can be enrolled in the class. the add function in the class controller is

```
public function add()
{
    $class = $this->Classes->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $class = $this->Classes->patchEntity($class, $this->request->getData());
        if ($this->Classes->save($class)) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The class has been saved.'));

        $this->loadModel('Lessons');

        $date = $class->start_date;

        // Create lessons for eack week of the class
        while($date <= $class->end_date) {

            // Get the next lesson date after the start of the user's enrolment, then each week afterward using the loop

            $lesson = $this->Lessons->newEntity();
            $lesson->class_id = $class->id;
            $lesson->teacher_id = $class->teacher_id;
            $lesson->lesson_date = $date;

            $this->Lessons->save($lesson);

            $date = $date->modify('+1 week');
        }

        $choice = $class->waitlist;
        if ($choice == "yes"){
            $this ->loadModel('Waitlist');
        }

        return $this->redirect(['controller' => 'schools', 'action' => 'view', $class->school_id]);
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('The class could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
}
$schools = $this->Classes->Schools->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->loadModel('Teachers');
    $teachers = $this->Teachers->find('list');



$this->set(compact('class', 'schools', 'teachers'));
$this->set('_serialize', ['class']);
}
```

The waitlist table has the fields: `waitlist_id`, `class_id`, `student_id` and `index`.
The class table has a field `waitlist_id` which is a foreign key.

Comment: What's not working about the code that you've shown?

Comment: The code is working but i dont know how to add a waitlist to the class object

Comment: A waitlist is a high-level concept, not something that can be "added to an object". The number of ways that something like that could be implemented are endless, so the question as written is really too broad for StackOverflow; it's likely that people will vote to close it for this reason. If you can provide more code-level details, we will be better able to help. For example, if you want a record to be added to the waitlist table in the function you've shown, then show the "if" statement that would control that, or else explain the problem you're having crafting that particular piece.